# How to run shell commands using dart on macOS

Tags: macos, shell, flutter, dart

I used Dart process to make shell commands on macOS. I used Flutter to make the macOS app. Now I want to run shell commands from the app.

**Command for running app**

```
/Users/lihongjun/shell/libs/zipalign -v 4 "/Users/lihongjun/Downloads/app-release.apk" "/Users/lihongjun/Documents/test/tempApk/app_aligned.apk" ,
```

**Error:**

```
 sh: /Users/Shared/shell/libs/zipalign: Operation not permitted
```

I have searched a lot but I can't resolve this, like process_runner, shell, system plug.

If I execute shell on mac's Terminal it works well.

```
bool rsult = System.invoke('/Users/Shared/shell/libs/zipalign -v 4');
print('result:$rsult');
ProcessCmd cmd = ProcessCmd('java', ['-version'],runInShell: false,);
runCmd(cmd).then((value) {
  print(value.stdout.toString());
});
```

Now I want to use the same in Dart code to make the shell commands.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This may not be useful to you since you're using Flutter, but to answer the question that is in the title (for anyone stumbling upon this writing a non-Flutter app) you should take a look at the `dart:io` library and its `run` method:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Process/run.html

> Starts a process and runs it non-interactively to completion. The process run is executable with the specified arguments.